# Jquery alert() works but not addclass() or anything else

Tags: jquery

I try to add an "active" class to a 'a' tag on a 'div' using jquery.
When I put Alert() instead of addclass(), it finds the target (#active0).
But when I insert addclass() or anything else , nothing happens.
I'm new on Jquery (and on Forums :) ) and  surely forgot something or don't understand a concept.
**Question:**
How could I do to see the .active class appears on my html to activate the .active class css properties on the web page?
Thank you all in advance for your help and advice.

You could find code bellow.

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("document").on("click","#active0", function () {  
        $(this).addclass("active");
        });
   });
```

```css
.folder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 130px;
    height:30px;  
}

.folder a{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(1, 113, 185, 0.8);
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border:1px solid rgba(1, 113, 185, 0.8);
    background-color: white;
    transition-duration:0.6s;  
}

.folder a.active{
    border:3px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<hmtl>
  <body>
      <div id="parent2" class="folder">
        <a id="active2" href="#">test</a>
      </div>
      <div id="parent1" class="folder">
        <a id="active1" href="#">test1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="parent" class="folder">
        <a id="active0" href="#">test2</a>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</hmtl>
```

[Console view when click on (a) tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDDi.png)

Comment: You can check the browser console to see the error. However, what is obvious from your code, you have to use "addClass" instead of "addclass"

Comment: As above, but there's no error (yet) as it's not getting that far - change to `$(document).on...` not `$("document")`

Comment: For your next step, change `.on("click", "#active0"...` to `.on("click", ".folder>a"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 error:

1. `addClass`  not `addclass` , the litter `C` is capital. jQuery uses camelCase syntax. [read more >](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)
2. `$(document)` not `$("document")` because its not an element inside your page. [read more >](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#active0", function () {  
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.folder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 130px;
    height:30px;  
}

.folder a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(1, 113, 185, 0.8);
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border:1px solid rgba(1, 113, 185, 0.8);
    background-color: white;
    transition-duration:0.6s;  
}

.folder a.active{
    border:3px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<hmtl>
  <body>
      <div id="parent2" class="folder">
        <a id="active2" href="#">test</a>
      </div>
      <div id="parent1" class="folder">
        <a id="active1" href="#">test1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="parent" class="folder">
        <a id="active0" href="#">test2</a>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: Finally it only works on jsfiddle or snippet but not on my app.

Comment: Do you have an Idea regarding the browsers  behavior?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your console when clicking the `a` ? and make sure that you don't have any duplicated id's .

Comment: Also scripts order is very important, you must call jQuery library first and before your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`addclass` should be [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-className)

Use following code

```
$("#active0").on("click", function () {
      $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Or if you are creating div dynamically use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#active0", function () {
      $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#active0").on("click", function () {
         $(this).addClass("active");
     });
});
```

```css
.folder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 130px;
    height:30px;  
}

.folder a{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(1, 113, 185, 0.8);
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border:1px solid rgba(1, 113, 185, 0.8);
    background-color: white;
    transition-duration:0.6s;  
}

.folder a.active{
    border:3px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<hmtl>
  <body>
      <div id="parent2" class="folder">
        <a id="active2" href="#">test</a>
      </div>
      <div id="parent1" class="folder">
        <a id="active1" href="#">test1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="parent" class="folder">
        <a id="active0" href="#">test2</a>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: Finally I claim victory too early...it works on snippet or jsfiddle but not on browsers.I have added : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.searchable@1.1.0/jquery.searchable.min.js"></script>  But nothing has changed. Do you have idea regarding this behaviour?